# Uma pergunta com recompensa expirada, mas ainda no tempo de tolerância, não deveria aparecer na aba "Com recompensa"?

Tags: debate, bug, status-intencional, recompensa

Eu procurei esta pergunta *[Qual é a diferença entre Cubos, Datasets e Tabelas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/555293/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-cubos-datasets-e-tabelas)* na aba `"Com recompensa"`, mas a mesma não constava. Realizei a busca manual e encontrei a mesma com a mensagem:

> Essa recompensa terminou. Respostas para essa pergunta podem receber uma recompensa de `+50` em reputação. O Prazo de tolerência termina em 18 horas. Costamilam quer atrair mais atenção para essa pergunta.

---

**Inclusive tem um erro de digitação: `tolerência` => `tolerância`.**

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ainda tem uma recompensa ativa, mesmo que no tempo de tolerância de 24h, faltando 18h no momento em que publico esta pergunta. Porém a mesma não aparece na aba `"Com recompensa"`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Este comportamento está correto?
- Ao meu julgamento, como vai atrair mais resposta se não está destacada na aba. Talvez seja um bug?

Comment: O funcionamento está de acordo, conforme o [FAQ do meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/401803): "*... bounty offerers may award bounties up to 24 hours after the bounty period ends (known as the grace period), to allow them to evaluate answers posted at the end of the bounty period. During the grace period, **there will be no indication in the questions lists (e.g. front page, bountied tab) that the question has a bounty***"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O comportamento está corretíssimo já que a recompensa terminou, como é informado na mensagem. Não tem porque aparecer entre as perguntas com recompensa ativa porque ela não está mais ativa, o período de divulgação encerrou e agora o máximo que ainda pode fazer é dar a recompensa a uma das respostas dadas durante o período que ela foi divulgada (não sei dizer o que acontece com as que forem feitas no período de tolerância, provavelmente aceitam também).

O período de tolerância existe para você avaliar melhor as respostas dadas e dar uma chance maior de você fazer antes de não poder mais e não perder a oportunidade porque ficou um dia fora da plataforma. Definitivamente o objetivo desse mecanismo não é atrair mais respostas, isso deveria ter ocorrido nos 7 dias.

No período de tolerância tem uma recompensa pendente e não ativa.

[Pode ver mais sobre](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). [Mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).

De fato há um erro de digitação.